# connect to RDS mysql via ELB terminated SSL

Tags: mysql, ssl, intellij-idea, rds

I have set up a custom port listener on `AWS ELB for MYSQL with ELB SSL` termination. This is forwarded to RDS on another port. When using without ELB SSL termination the connection works fine. Adding the SSL termination I get no connection.

***This is NOT RDS SSL termination, it is SSL termination on the ELB.

```
ELB
port in 30000 with ACM wildcard cert -> 40000 RDS MYSQL
```

using intellij as a test connection

```
dbc:mysql://ssl.myurl.com:30000/myuser
advanced -> useSSL:true
```

I also tried `dbc:mysql://ssl.myurl.com:30000/myuser?useSSL=true`

Is there a different setting I should use

Comment: Is MySQL server configured to use secure connection?

Comment: Note also that for the ssl connection to work you should [configure the client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html) to use it: add server certificate (to jvm truststore) and client certificate (to java keystore). You specify it in [SSH/SSL tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html?search=data%20source#ssl) of the Data Source. If password is required for keystore and truststore, specify it in **Advanced** tab for *clientCertificateKeyStorePassword* and *trustCertificateKeyStorePassword* options.

Comment: @Andrey why do I need any of his key store as the connection is not to mysql, rather than to the ELB as normal `https://` would be? I don't have the certs as they are generated by AWS cert manager. The mysql never sees any encryption request.

Comment: I'm not sure then why do you need to use `useSSL=true` property if MySQL server never sees the encrypted request?